# How can I make display resolution changes persistent

Tags: resolution

I successfully got my computer to display at `1440x900` resolution using the following steps. The problem is, I can't figure out how to make the changes persistent even after restarting the system.

Here are the steps

- Use xrandr to make sure that the new mode can fit within the maximum framebuffer size
  Code:

  ```
  xrandr | grep maximum
  ```
- Use gtf to create a mode line
  Code:

  ```
  gtf 1440 900 59.9
  ```
- Add new mode using xrandr
  Code:

  ```
  xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
  ```
- Add this newly added mode to the desired output (VGA/LVDS etc)
  Code:

  ```
  xrandr --addmode VGA 1440x900_59.90
  ```
- Choose the new mode
  Code:

  ```
  xrandr --output VGA --mode 1440x900_59.90
  ```

Any Suggestions for making these changes persistent?

Comment: Please mention your GPU's brand name and model. Thank you.

Comment: you can change it in the xorg.conf file...

Comment: ok, but what exactly should I put in.  xorg.conf file is blank.

Comment: I have Radeon Xpress 200

Comment: the website where I found the code from my first post said to add:

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Primary Screen"
Device "ATI Technologies, Inc. M22 [Radeon Mobility M300]"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
Modes "1280x1024" "1024x768" "640x480"
EndSubSection
EndSection

But that didn't work

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned.